# Pandas: Alternating iterrows() from left to right and right to left

Tags: python, pandas

I'm pretty new to programming, and so far this problem has been 'above my paygrade', so any help you can give on this is greatly appreciated!

I have a `DataFrame` object that looks like this:

```
               Dan          Mike            Dave
0  Adrian Peterson    Eddie Lacy  Jamaal Charles
1   Calvin Johnson   Leveon Bell      Dez Bryant
```

I would like to create a new `DataFrame` object that looks like this:

```
             Player       Drafter
0   Adrian Peterson           Dan
1        Eddie Lacy          Mike
2    Jamaal Charles          Dave
3        Dez Bryant          Dave
4       Leveon Bell          Mike
5    Calvin Johnson           Dan
```

I'm not sure how to iterate through the first row, left to right, and then through the second row from right to left.

Thank you so much for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in this case it's good to show at least 3 rounds in order to check the code (assuming you want something more general than for just 2 rounds), so I'll expand the sample data:

```
               Dan          Mike            Dave
0  Adrian Peterson    Eddie Lacy  Jamaal Charles
1   Calvin Johnson   Leveon Bell      Dez Bryant
2        Tom Brady  Lionel Messi    Lebron James
```

First of all, use `stack()` to get a tentative draft order.

```
df2 = df.stack().reset_index().reset_index()
df2.columns = ['Order','Round','Drafter','Player']

   Order  Round Drafter           Player
0      0      0     Dan  Adrian Peterson
1      1      0    Mike       Eddie Lacy
2      2      0    Dave   Jamaal Charles
3      3      1     Dan   Calvin Johnson
4      4      1    Mike      Leveon Bell
5      5      1    Dave       Dez Bryant
6      6      2     Dan        Tom Brady
7      7      2    Mike     Lionel Messi
8      8      2    Dave     Lebron James
```

Note that order is correct for Rounds 0 and 2, but not 1.  A fairly easy way to fix the order for round 1 is to multiply by negative 1 (more specifically all rounds not divisible by 2) and then sort:

```
df2['Order'] = np.where( df2['Round'].mod(2)==1, -df2['Order'], df2['Order'] )

df3 = df2.sort(['Round','Order']).reset_index(drop=True)

   Order  Round Drafter           Player
0      0      0     Dan  Adrian Peterson
1      1      0    Mike       Eddie Lacy
2      2      0    Dave   Jamaal Charles
3     -5      1    Dave       Dez Bryant
4     -4      1    Mike      Leveon Bell
5     -3      1     Dan   Calvin Johnson
6      6      2     Dan        Tom Brady
7      7      2    Mike     Lionel Messi
8      8      2    Dave     Lebron James
```

At this point the draft order is now correctly held by the index and you can delete the Order column (I'm just leaving it there to make it more obvious how the code works).

Answer (score 0):

This solution iterates through each row in the DataFrame via `iterrows`, reverses the row if it is odd numbered row `[::(-1 if n % 2 else 1)]`, and then concatenates the results together with the list of Drafters which has been repeated by the number of rows in the DataFrame via `df.columns.tolist() * df.shape[0]`.  The players and drafters are joined via a `zip` function, and then passed to the DataFrame constructor.

```
draft = pd.DataFrame(zip(pd.concat([pd.Series(row.values)[::(-1 if n % 2 else 1)] 
                                    for n, row in df.iterrows()], 
                                   ignore_index=True), 
                         df.columns.tolist() * df.shape[0]), 
                     columns=['Player', 'Drafter'])
draft['round'] = 1 + draft.index.values // df.shape[1]

>>> draft
            Player Drafter  round
0  Adrian Peterson     Dan      1
1       Eddie Lacy    Mike      1
2   Jamaal Charles    Dave      1
3       Dez Bryant     Dan      2
4      Leveon Bell    Mike      2
5   Calvin Johnson    Dave      2
6        Tom Brady     Dan      3
7     Lionel Messi    Mike      3
8     Lebron James    Dave      3
```

Comment: Thank you this is a great answer! The only thing is that I was hoping to keep the Drafter matched up with the Player as well. But thank you so much for your help!